Why does stat_poly_eq give a wrong formula for the trendline when plotting the graph on a log-scale?
My problem is when I plot the same data with linear and with log-transformed axes, the equation that is calculated by stat_poly_eq gives is different between both plots (wrong in the log-transformed plot). What could be the reason for that, and is there a simple way to fix that?
See below code for example:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

x <- runif(100, min = 10, max = 1000)
y <- 2 * x + rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 50)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, use_label(c("eq", "adj.R2", "n")))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10") + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10") + 
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, use_label(c("eq", "adj.R2", "n")))


Both are correct. But the models are different. When you apply a transformation via the scale you are transforming the data, i.e. in your second plot both x and y are transformed to a log scale before estimating the model, i.e. you are estimating lm(log10(y) ~ log10(x), data = df) whereas in the first plot it is lm(y ~ x, data = df). If you only want to log transform the axes perhaps you want + coord_trans(x = "log10", y = "log10").
